# tkinter entry fill with value selected from dictionary

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to fill entry boxes with values selected from dictionary.
List of dictionaries is compiled from a csv file. Here is the code:

```
import os
import csv
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import *

def show():
    record =[]
    details = open('c.record.csv','r')
    reader = csv.DictReader(details)
    for line in reader:
        record.append(line)
    return record

def recordDetails():
    name = ent_user.get()
    password = ent_pw.get()
    city = ent_city.get()
    code = ent_code.get()
    if len(name) != 0 and len(password) != 0 and len(city) != 0 and len(code) != 0:       
        with open('c.record.csv', 'a') as add:
            w = csv.writer(add)
            w.writerow([name,password,city,code])
            add.close
            lbl_result["text"] = "record saved"
    else:
         lbl_result["text"] = "values cannot be empty"
    return True

def SaveToFile():
    name = ent_user.get()
    data = show()
    for elem in data:
        if name in elem.values():
            lbl_result["text"] = "record exist already"
            return False
    recordDetails()
    return True

def display() :
    lbl_result["text"] = show()
    record = show()
    for n, dicts in enumerate(record):
        for v, k in dicts.items():
            position = n
            user = dicts['name']
        lbl_record = tk.Label(master=frm_details, height=1, width=40, bg = 'white', relief=tk.GROOVE, text=user,justify="right")
        lbl_record.grid(row=1+position, column=0, padx=5)
        def select():
            Clear()
            ent_user.insert(tk.END,dicts['name'])
            ent_pw.insert(tk.END,dicts['password'])
            ent_city.insert(tk.END,dicts['city'])
            ent_code.insert(tk.END,dicts['code']) 
        btn_recSelect = tk.Button(master=frm_details ,width=5, bg = 'white', text='select',command=select)
        btn_recSelect.grid(row=1+position, column=1, padx=2,sticky=tk.W)
    return True

def Connect():
    if len(ent_user.get()) != 0:
        lbl_result["text"] =  "connecting to "+ent_user.get()

def Clear() :
    user = ent_user.delete(0,END)
    pw = ent_pw.delete(0,END)
    city = ent_city.delete(0,END)
    code = ent_code.delete(0,END)

#def update(window):
    #window.update()
    
screen = tk.Tk()
screen.title ("tk files interaction")
screen.minsize(width=400, height=300)
screen.maxsize(width=900, height=700)
screen.rowconfigure(0, minsize=50, weight=1)
screen.columnconfigure(0, minsize=60, weight=1)

screen.update()

#FORM to collect connectivity details 
frm_connEntryArea = tk.Frame(master=screen,height=10, borderwidth=1, highlightbackground="orange", highlightthickness=1)
frm_connEntryArea.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.N, padx=10, pady=5)

lbl_user = tk.Label(master=frm_connEntryArea, text="name:")
lbl_user.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.NW, padx=5, pady=3)
ent_user = tk.Entry(master=frm_connEntryArea,width=30)
ent_user.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=tk.NW, padx=5, pady=3)

lbl_pw = tk.Label(master=frm_connEntryArea, text="password:")
lbl_pw.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.NW, padx=5, pady=3)
ent_pw = tk.Entry(master=frm_connEntryArea,width=30)
ent_pw.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=tk.NW, padx=5, pady=3)

lbl_city = tk.Label(master=frm_connEntryArea, text="city")
lbl_city.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=tk.NW, padx=5, pady=3)
ent_city = tk.Entry(master=frm_connEntryArea,width=30)
ent_city.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=tk.NW, padx=5, pady=3)

lbl_code = tk.Label(master=frm_connEntryArea, text="code:")
lbl_code.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=tk.NW, padx=5, pady=3)
ent_code = tk.Entry(master=frm_connEntryArea,width=30)
ent_code.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=tk.NW, padx=5, pady=3)
ent_code.insert(tk.END,"20")
ent_code.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: clear_entry(ent_code))

#connect,save and clear details
btn_save = tk.Button(master=frm_connEntryArea,text="Save",width=10,fg="black",command=SaveToFile)
btn_save.grid(column=0, row=4, sticky=tk.NW, padx=5, pady=3)
btn_clear = tk.Button(master=frm_connEntryArea,text="Clear",width=10,fg="black",command=Clear)
btn_clear.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=tk.NW, padx=5, pady=3)
btn_conn = tk.Button(master=frm_connEntryArea,text="Connect",width=10,fg="black",command=Connect)
btn_conn.grid(column=2, row=4, sticky=tk.NW, padx=5, pady=3)

#FORM to shows connectivity results and errors
frm_logs = tk.Frame(master=screen,height=10,bg="gray",relief=tk.GROOVE,highlightbackground="orange")
frm_logs.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.NW, padx=5, pady=3)

lbl_result = tk.Label(master=frm_logs, height=8, width=50,relief=tk.GROOVE, bg = 'white', text="Logs",wraplength=300,justify="left")
lbl_result.grid(row=0, column=0)

#FORM to shows Existing Record
frm_record = tk.Frame(master=screen,height=10,bg="gray")
frm_record.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=tk.N, padx=5, pady=3)

lbl_record = tk.Label(master=frm_record, height=1, width=40, bg = 'white', relief=tk.GROOVE, text='Record',wraplength=200,justify="left")
lbl_record.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5)
btn_recDisplay = tk.Button(master=frm_record ,width=5, bg = 'white', text='Display',command =display)
btn_recDisplay.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2,sticky=tk.W)

frm_details = tk.Frame(master=frm_record,height=10,bg="gray")
frm_details.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.NW, padx=5, pady=3)

lbl_record = tk.Label(master=frm_details , height=1, width=30, bg = 'white', relief=tk.GROOVE, text='user',justify="right")
lbl_record.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5)

#FORM to exit
frm_exit = tk.Frame(master=screen,height=50,width= 300, bg="orange")
frm_exit.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=NE, padx=5, pady=3)
frm_exit.grid_propagate(0)

btn_refresh = tk.Button(master=frm_exit, text="Refresh")
btn_refresh.grid(row=2, column=3,sticky=E, padx=10,pady=10)

btn_exit = tk.Button(master=frm_exit, text="Exit", command=screen.destroy)
btn_exit.grid(row=2, column=4, sticky=E, padx=10,pady=10)

# added at the end
screen.mainloop()
```

csv structure:

```
name,password,city,code
apple,1234,rome,20 
banana,2345,paris,20 
cherry,3456,london,21
```

I am concerned with the def display() : and  def select(): functions. These works in displaying and selecting. The problem is when ‘select’ is pressed the latest dictionary value form the list is used to fill the entries boxes, I would like the entries to be filled with the values that correspond to the user display in the line.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.
I have adjust the code with the guidance found here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/looping-through-buttons-in-tkinter/

```
def select(u,pwd,cy,co):
    Clear()
    ent_user.insert(tk.END,u)
    ent_pw.insert(tk.END,pwd)
    ent_city.insert(tk.END,cy)
    ent_code.insert(tk.END,co)     

def display() :
    lbl_result["text"] = show()
    record = show()
    for n, line in enumerate(record):
        position = n
        user = line['name']
        for k,v in line.items():   
            def action(x = line['name'], p = line['password'], c = line['city'], d = line['code']): 
                return select(x,p,c,d)  
        lbl_record = tk.Label(master=frm_details, height=1, width=40, bg = 'white', relief=tk.GROOVE, text=user,justify="right")
        lbl_record.grid(row=1+position, column=0, padx=5)
        btn_recSelect = tk.Button(master=frm_details ,width=5, bg = 'white', text='select',command= action)
        btn_recSelect.grid(row=1+position, column=1, padx=2,sticky=tk.W)    
    return True
```

I had to create an aditional function to point to action the entry update and add an addidional for looop, the first loop through the list, the second through the dictionary items.